# Filtering null values from a structured field in a Pyspark dynamic frame

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have an extremely nested json, after filtering only the categories fields I want to deal with, I am left with the same complex structure/schema for my column 'data' as the original dataframe:

```
+--------------------+...
|                data|    
+--------------------+...
|{null, null, 833,...|...
```

and the structure of data includes around 250 nested fields of which 95% are empty.

My aim is to turn the data column into an aggregate of only the **non-null** fields, ideally only a subset of those that are non-null. But the structured schema is inherited from the point where I read the data, and I cant seem to find a method that will re-create the schema again.

methods I have tried:

1. `filtered4.filter(f.col('data').isNotNull()) / isNull()`
   But that wipes out the entire row / does'nt do anything.
2. ws_concat and coalesce()  like this:
   `df.withColumn("data", concat_ws(", ", coalesce(col("data.street"), ""), coalesce(col("data.city.neighborhood"), ""), coalesce(col("address.state"), ""))) ...`
   but that is not an option because I have 100's of fields.
3. Casting my 'data' column into a string and then cleaning it using regex, but then I loose the structure/names of the fields I want to keep

For context these are structured fields that are dynamic (ie request headers for a website), and change in structure depending on the data, therefore I want to have it in one place, and access it only if i want. I thought of best to keep it as a string type without all these nulls ("{null, null, 833,.."), but I am very open to advice from more experienced pysparkers in the crowd.

Comment: could you show the input json file ?

Comment: Have you tried https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_remove.html?highlight=functions

Comment: the input json file can be around 10mb. Don't think I can publicaly share it though

Comment: The main issue is, I need to parquet a very complex json, intelligently and dealing with such large json can be overwhelming, so Im trying to cut it into pieces and discover set schemates for each. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second option you tried (and the pain point there), you can try the following to collect all fields in the struct column.

```
import typing
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

def construct(prefix: str, fields: typing.List) -> typing.List:
   '''
   Recursive function to find all nested fields in the struct field
   '''
   # List holding all nested fields found in this call
   found_fields = []
   # Loop over the list of fields passed as an argument
   for field in fields:
      if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
         found_fields += \
            [
               prefix+'.'+item for item in
               construct(field.name, field.dataType.fields)
            ]
      else:
         found_fields.append(prefix+'.'+field.name)
   return found_fields

def all_nested_fields(df: DataFrame, col: str) -> typing.List[str]:
   '''
   Collect all nested fields in a struct column in a Spark data frame
   '''
   if isinstance(df.schema[col].dataType, StructType):
      print('%s is a struct column. Finding all nested fields' % (col, ))
      return construct(col, df.schema[col].dataType.fields)
   else:
      print('%s is not a struct column.' % (col, ))


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
((((("Iran", 30)),), "Sajad", "Safarveisi"), "Tehran", "Persian Golf"),
((((("USA", 40)),), "James", "Baker"), "Washington", "Wall Street"),
((((("Germany", 25)),), "Patrick", "Gottmann"), "Colon", "Black Forest")]

schema = StructType([
StructField("name", StructType([
        StructField("details", StructType([
                StructField("nationality", StructType([
                    StructField("country", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)
                ]), False)]), False),
        StructField("firstname", StringType(), True),
        StructField("lastname", StringType(), True),
    ]), False),
StructField("city", StringType(), True),
StructField("attribute", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

# All nested fields in the column 'name'
nested_fields = all_nested_fields(df, 'name')
# Create a spark data frame from them (example operation)
df.select(*[F.col(field) for field in nested_fields]).show()
```